# Windows Services (error 1053) event log trigger

Tags: c#, error-handling, windows-services, event-log, winlogon

I am new to programming and I have this project due on coming Tuesday. What I am trying to do is if a user enters a wrong password on the logon screen the cam takes the picture. I tried to implement my code in services but it gives me error 1053. I was wondering if somebody could fix this code for me or if file watcher is of use in my code. Please help!

```
namespace SampleWS
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        private WebCam camera;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPause(string[] args)
        {
            bool infinite = false;
            LogonChecker(infinite);           
        }

        protected virtual void OnContinue(string[] args)
        {
            bool infinite = true;
            LogonChecker(infinite);
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {            
            bool infinite = true;
            LogonChecker(infinite);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {                        
            bool infinite = false;
            LogonChecker(infinite);          
        }

        DateTime mytime = DateTime.MinValue;

        public void LogonChecker(bool infinity)
        {
            string queryString =
               "<QueryList>" +
               "  <Query Id=\"\" Path=\"Security\">" +
               "    <Select Path=\"Security\">" +
               "        *[System[(Level &lt;= 0) and" +
               "        TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]" +
               "    </Select>" +
               "    <Suppress Path=\"Application\">" +
               "        *[System[(Level = 0)]]" +
               "    </Suppress>" +
               "    <Select Path=\"System\">" +
               "        *[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3) and" +
               "        TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]" +
               "    </Select>" +
               "  </Query>" +
               "</QueryList>";


            camera = new WebCam();

         while (infinity)
          {
                EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, queryString);
                eventsQuery.ReverseDirection = true;
                EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
                EventRecord eventInstance;
                Int32 eventexists3 = new Int32();
                EventLog mylog = new EventLog();
                for (eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent(); null != eventInstance; eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent())
                {

                        eventexists3 = eventInstance.Id.CompareTo(4625);

                        if (eventexists3 == 0)
                        {
                            if (eventInstance.TimeCreated.Value > mytime)
                            {
                                mytime = eventInstance.TimeCreated.Value;
                                camera.Connect();
                                Image image = camera.GetBitmap();
                                image.Save(@"D:\Audio\testimage3.jpg");
                                camera.Disconnect();
                                eventInstance = null;
                                break;
                            }             
                        }
                    EventLogRecord logRecord = (EventLogRecord)eventInstance;
                    LogonChecker(infinity);
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Modification of the Windows login system is an advanced topic, there are all sorts of potential issues (including security). I would suggest starting with something much simpler. (We can't help with the specifics of the question unless you tell us on what line of your code and under what circumstances the error is occurring.)

Comment: @Richard my code runs fine as a console application but as a service gives me error 1053.

Comment: See my answer: the execution model for services is rather different to other executables.

Comment: Do we have alternative for this? If I have to run  my code at windows logon what shall I do ?

Comment: There are a number of options, but hooking into the core of Windows authentication (to detect failed logins) is not easy and I expect it would be a very bad idea to do it in .NET. There is a plugin model for `lsass.exe` (eg. for alternative authorisation) but any defect is likely to break Windows. You use of WMI from a service to detect failed authentication events might work (but without login session will the camera work?), but you need to write the service correctly.

Comment: @Richard Do you know how to run processes in parallel. I have 3 functions  as
1. AuditFailureChecker();
2. RegeditChecker();
3. FirewallChecker();

Now if I execute them function 1 would run, then function 2 and function 3. Each of my functions have infinite loops (unless I get to fix windows service error 1053). I  want them to run parallel. Any Idea ?

Comment: Multiple threads is the answer. But even better would be to avoid infinite loops and respond to events (eg. receive WMI event and process). If you arrange things right you can avoid any manual creating of threads by using the thread pool. Overall: have the OS call you when work needed; don't poll the OS.

Comment: There is EventLogWatcher which monitors and respond you back. I tried a million times to have it working with my above code but I failed.

Comment: "tried a million times": so simplify and make something simpler work (eg. from a custom event log that doesn't have the security restrictions of the security log). Sometimes development tasks take more than simple retries, but re-thinking the problem.

Comment: So far I am not having security issues. My code without infinite loop works fine but I need to run it in infinite loop for that reason I needed to try EventLogWatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my comment, this is easy. [Check what the error 1053 means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681383.aspx):

> **ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT**
>
> 1053 (0x41D)
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Your overrides of [`ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx) methods like [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) need to return as soon as possible. If you want to perform any ongoing work either subscribe to events or spin up a worker thread.

The .NET documentation on MSDN doesn't really cover much about the execution model of services, for this you need to look at the Win32 documentation: *[About Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*.

Comment: I have read about error 1053 but since my programming is weak. I can understand a lot but its hard for me to implement while not knowing the syntax and library functions.

Comment: Hi, I am blocked by SO and I have a question. I am trying to make Task Scheduler in c# I have some problems regarding EventTrigger etrigger;   etrigger.SetBasic("Security", "Microsoft Windows security auditing.", 4625); this creates a duplicate "Microsoft Windows security auditing." so I tried to use etrigger.GetBasic which gives error. I have a third option here. etrigger.Subscription. Can you please guide me how to use GetBasic or Subscription

Comment: @CurtisHagen That is a completely different question: if you have a question ban then sort it out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans (and while you are at it: [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317167/creating-event-trigger-in-task-scheduler