# Creating Event Trigger in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, event-log, eventtrigger, eventlog-source

I am new to programming and I have found a code to register a task under root folder in task scheduler.
I have the below code in which there is a method "eTrigger.SetBasic("Security", "Microsoft Windows security auditing.", 4625)" what it does is it creates a duplicate "Log Name" and "Log Source" and bottom line my code does not work.
I want to use eTrigger.GetBasic() or eTrigger.Subscription to address my code to the actual event logs. When I use eTRigger.GetBasic() it with the arguments I am giving in eTRigger.SetBasic("Security", "Microsoft Windows security auditing.", 4625) it gives me error

Can someone fix this code for me?

My code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            // Create a new task definition and assign properties
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
            // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
            // whether user is logged on or not
            EventTrigger eTrigger = (EventTrigger)td.Triggers.Add(new EventTrigger());
            EventLog securityLog = new EventLog("Security", System.Environment.MachineName);
            //this is where I see problem. I want to use eTrigger.GetBasic
            eTrigger.SetBasic("Security", "Microsoft Windows security auditing.", 4625);
            eTrigger.Enabled = true;
            eTrigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.Zero;
            // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"));
            // Register the task in the root folder
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("test", td);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method has invalid arguments . Arguments must be passed with out keyword. What I think if I am able to give them a path to Event Log and Event Source it would do the trick. But I don't know what path to give

Comment: which Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper are you using?

Comment: using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
Infact I have tried to use the below but it didn't work also.
 
EventLog securityLog = new EventLog("Security", System.Environment.MachineName);
securityLog.Source = "Microsoft Windows security auditing.";
securityLog.Log="Security";
eTrigger.GetBasic(securityLog.Log,securityLog.Source,4625)